# Installing Blackberry Webworks on Vista

Tags: blackberry-webworks

How do I install Blackberry Webworks on Vista? Do I need to install a web server as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download and install webworks on Vista. It's not officially supported, but I have heard people say it works.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/sdk

You don't need a web server.

---

If you are having any specific problems when attempting to install post the details.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Manage to get it install on Vista. I did install web server as well, XAMPP and so far it's running pretty good.

Comment: @Jamie are you using XAMPP because you want to use ASP or PHP within your webworks application? Because I don't think that is possible. Please check question as answered if your problem is solved.